# como evitar que la clase "createTextFinder" en Google App Script, busque y borre una palabra no elegida explicitamente?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Tengo el siguiente spreadsheet :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo quiero borrar todas las celdas que tengan como nombre "lucas". Por lo tanto luego de muchisimas frustraciones logre adaptar un codigo perfecto para mis propositos, es el siguiente :

```
function textFinder2(){
  let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   .createTextFinder("lucas")
   .matchEntireCell(false)
   .matchCase(false)
   .matchFormulaText(false)
   .ignoreDiacritics(true)
   .findAll();

ranges.forEach(function (range) {
    range.clearContent();
  });
}
```

Luego de aplicar el codigo obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo funciona casi perfecto. Ahora bien, Si nos damos cuenta en las celdas A1 y A7 están dos "lucas", el código borra esas celdas, pero también nos damos cuenta que borró la celda A5 (gianlucas torres). Esto es debido a que gianlucas tiene la palabra "lucas" adentro.

Mi pregunta es como puedo evitar borrar una celda donde un nombre tenga **una parte** del texto lucas. Por ejemplo el nombre "gianlucas torre" tiene el texto lucas adentro (gian*lucas*) y por eso borra esa celda y NO quiero que la borre.

Quiero borrar las celdas que contengan explicitamente solo el texto lucas ( digo **contengan**, osea si la celda solamente tiene el texto lucas  que borre esa celda entera y si la celda contiene "lucas rincon" o "lucas americo" también borre esa celda entera)

Intenté cambiando el argumento de "matchEntireCell(false)" por true : "matchEntireCell(true)", pero no me serviría porque obligatoriamente la celda debe tener **solo** la palabra lucas y la mayoría de las veces el texto "lucas" no esta solo en la celda.

Answer (score 0):

Tu función hace dos cosas:

1. Busca lo que quieres sustituir.
2. Modifica lo encontrado en el paso 1.

Tu paso 1 ya es correcto por lo que cambiar **matchEntireCell** pasandole *true* o *false* no te generará lo que requieres.

Lo que necesitas es modificar tu paso 2.

Tu paso 2 indica en este momento que por cada elemento encontrado se invoque al método **clearContent** es decir que se borre el contenido.

```
ranges.forEach(function (range) {
    range.clearContent();
  });
```

Evidentemente esto es lo que hay que cambiar.
La pregunta natural es ¿Qué quiero que se haga con cada coincidencia?. En este caso con cada coincidencia según lo que has puesto, lo que deseas es:

- a) Tomar el texto de la celda.
- b) Quitar la palabra lucas del texto.
- c) Asignar ese texto sin lucas a la celda.

Para el paso a) podemos usar el método **getValue**.

El método **getValue** devuelve el texto que tiene la celda. Esto lo podemos almacenar en una variable:

```
let texto = range.getValue();
```

Para el paso b) podemos apoyarnos de la funcion **replace** y de otra variable para almacenar el texto sin la palabra lucas.

```
let textoSinLucas = texto.replace('lucas','');
```

Para el paso c) podemos apoyarnos del método **setValue** .

```
range.setValue(  textoSinLucas );
```

Es decir la rutina completa quearía como:

```
ranges.forEach(function (range) {
        
    let texto = range.getValue();
    let textoSinLucas = texto.replace('lucas','');
    range.setValue(  textoSinLucas );
    
  });
```

Pruebalo por favor y coméntame si es lo que necesitas.

=====================================================

De acuerdo a las aclaraciones hechas a la pregunta original mi nueva propuesta de solución es completamente diferente a lo que había mencionado originalmente:

Primeramente diré que la función de la pregunta hace dos cosas:

1. Busca lo que quieres sustituir.
2. Modifica lo encontrado en el paso 1.

El paso 2 es correcto y no requiere ningún cambio.

El paso 1 requiere afinar su búsqueda considerando los siguientes casos:

- a) Deberá encontrar aquellas celdas cuyo texto solo este formado por la palabra lucas.
- b) Deberá encontrar aquellas celdas cuyo texto inicie por la palabra lucas y enseguida haya un espacio.
- c) Deberá encontrar aquellas celdas cuyo texto termine con la palabra lucas, donde esta palabra deberá estar antecedida de un espacio en blanco.
- d) Deberá encontrar aquellas celdas cuyo texto tenga un espacio en
  blanco seguido de la palabra lucas seguido de otro espacio en blanco.

a) Encontrar las celdas cuyo texto solo este formado por la palabra lucas puede hacerse a través de la expresión regular:

```
"^lucas$"
```

**^** Es el simbolo que indica el inicio de un renglón.

**$** Es el simbolo que indica el final de un renglón.

Las comillas indican que la expresión regular es en realidad una cadena de caracteres.

Es decir *"^lucas$"* indica los renglones que entre su inicio y final solo tengan la palabra lucas.

b) Las celdas que empiecen por lucas seguido de un espacio en blanco pueden localizarse a través de la siguiente expresión regular:

```
"^lucas "
```

c) Las celdas que terminen en lucas y que estén antecedidas por un espacio en blanco pueden encontrarse usando la siguiente expresión regular:

```
" lucas$"
```

c) Las celda que tengan la palabra lucas antecedidas y precedidas por un espacio en blanco pueden encontrarse con la siguiente expresión regular:

```
" lucas "
```

Como queremos evaluar todos los casos al mismo tiempo podemos indicar un *or* a nivel de expresión regular. Esto lo haremos usando el carácter **|** :

```
"^lucas$|^lucas | lucas$| lucas "
```

Lo siguiente será incorporar esto al código.

Para ello al **TextFinder** le indicaremos que vamos a usar una expresión regular a través del método **useRegularExpression** pasando el valor de *true*. La expresión regular la pasaremos en el **createTextFinder**

```
let ranges = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
   .createTextFinder("^lucas$|^lucas | lucas$| lucas ")   
   .useRegularExpression(true)
   .matchCase(false)
   .matchFormulaText(false)
   .ignoreDiacritics(true)
   .findAll();
```

Notese que eh eliminado el uso de **matchEntireCell** pues en este caso es necesario que se evalué la celda entera (por defecto ese es el comportamiento por lo que puede omitirse la invocación al método).

Coméntame por favor si esto que te menciono te sirve como solución.

Comment: Como estas alvaro. Muchas Gracias. Voy a guardar tu codigo porque estoy seguro que me va a servir muchisimo en un futuro. . . . . . Sin embargo, ya lo probé y no es lo que estoy buscando. No se trata  de eliminar SOLO la palabra "lucas" de las celdas. Yo lo que quiero es que borre completas las celdas que contengan EXACTAMENTE la palabra "lucas" .  Cuando yo corro mi código elimina la celda que tiene la palabra "gianlucas" (porque este  tiene "lucas" adentro), y yo no quiero eso.

Comment: Ya edité la pregunta. La puedes volver a leer. Está mucho mas clara en lo que quiero.

Comment: Hola NIN. De acuerdo, si entonces el sentido es diferente a como lo había pensado. Editare la respuesta de acuerdo a la edición de tu pregunta.